# STRIPS representation of monkey in the lab

Tags: artificial-intelligence, planning

I have been reviewing some material on the representation of an AI plan given the STRIPS format, and found that different people seem to formulate the same problem in different ways.

For instance, Wikipedia has an example regarding the Monkey in the lab problem. The problem states that:

*A box is available that will enable the monkey to reach the bananas hanging from the ceiling if he climbs up on it. Initially, the monkey is at A, the bananas at B, and the box at C. The monkey and the box have height Low, but if the monkey climbs onto the box, he will have height High, the same as the bananas. The actions available to the monkey include Go from one place to another, Push an object from one place to another, ClimbUp onto or CLimbDown from an object, and Grasp or UnGrasp an object. Grasping the object results in holding the object if the monkey and the object are in the same place at the same height.*

Here is the Wikipedia plan (please note that it is not matched exactly to this problem description, but it is the same problem. It doesn't seem to implement Ungrasp, which is not important for this discussion):

[image: Wikipedia solution to problem]

Now nowhere in this plan can I see that the bananas are located at Level(high), so the only way this could actually be divulged from the plan would be to read through the entire set of Actions and deduce from there that the Monkey must be at Level(high) to interact with the bananas, hence they must be at Level(high).

Would it be a good idea to put this information in the Initial State, and have something like:

*Monkey(m) & Bananas(ba) & Box(bx) & Level(low) & Level(high) & Position(A) & Position(B) & Position(C) & At(m, A, low) & At(ba, B, high) & At(bx, C, low)*

It looks quite verbose like that, but at the same time, it allows the reader to understand the scenario just through reading the Initial State. I've also been told that we should not be using constants anywhere in STRIPS, so I thought declaring the A, B, and C as Positions was a good idea.

Is it that some people do it differently (which I feel would kind of ruin the idea of having a standardized language to represent things), or is it that one of the ways I have presented isn't in the correct format? I am new to STRIPS, so it is entirely possible (and likely) that I am missing some key points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the greatest wikipedia ever.  The description of STRIPS is accurate, but a little outdated.

Generally you don't need to worry about defining all the variables in the initial state because the variables are defined by the domain (the P in the quadruple in the linked article).  For an intuition as to why, you have an operator for `MONKEY` in your initial state, but you're still introducing a free variable `m` that is not defined anywhere else.  You end up with a chicken and egg problem if you try to do it that way, so instead the facts in the system are just propositional variables which are effectively sentinel values that mean something to the users of the system, not the system itself.

You are correct that you need to define the level for each item as part of the initial state, but the initial state of the example actually correct considering the constraints that the bananas are *always* high, the box is *always* low and the monkey is the only thing that changes level.  I would probably change the example to have the `At` proposition take into account the object in question instead of using different proposition names for each object but that's just a style choice; the semantics are the same.

Operators in STRIPS are generally represented by 3 distinct components:

- **preconditions** - each variable in the preconditions list must exactly match the corresponding variable in the current state (trues must be true, falses must be falses) but you ignore all other variables not explicit in the preconditions
- **add effects** - when the action is performed, these are the effects that variables that are added to the state
- **delete effects** - when the action is performed, these are the effects that are deleted from the state
- and sometimes a 4th **cost** component when considering cost optimality

The post conditions listed in your example are the union of the add effects and delete effects.  The advantage of separating them will come later when you get into delete relaxation abstractions.

---

In your proposed initial state you have propositions that contain multiple properties for the same object (e.g. `At(bx, C, low)`).  This is typically avoided in favor of having a proposition for each property of each object in the state.  Doing it this way makes you end up with a larger state, but makes for a much simpler implementation since you don't have to decompose a state variable in order to identify the value of a specific property of an object in the preconditions list.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer, it has given some things to think about. I especially appreciate the points where you have said that in more advanced situations, I would want to go with a particular implementation; it is always good to focus on good conventions early and use them in all situations, just to re-enforce the concepts.